# Полоса загрузки html, css

Tags: html, css

Видел, что есть тэг в *HTML5* `progress`, но увы его нельзя стилизовать.

**Как вернее всего сделать что-то подобное?**

```css
.value,
progress {
        width: 100%;
 height: 10px;
 background: #ddd;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.value-box {
 height: 10px;
 background: #36c36e;
}
```

```html
<div id="skills">
   <p>C++ development</p>
   <progress value="23" max="100"></progress>
   
   <p>HTML5</p>
   <div class="value"><div class="value-box" style="width: 55%;"></div></div>
   
   <p>.NET</p>
   <div class="value"><div class="value-box" style="width: 74%;"></div></div>
   
   <p>jQuery</p>
   <div class="value"><div class="value-box" style="width: 65%;"></div></div>
   
   <p>Angular</p>
   <div class="value"><div class="value-box" style="width: 40%;"></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему нельзя стилизовать? Можно!

```css
.value {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

progress[value] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 70%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
}
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-image:
    -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, 
                            transparent 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 33%, 
                            rgba(0,0, 0, .1) 66%, transparent 66%),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(top, 
                            rgba(255, 255, 255, .25), 
                            rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #09c, #f44);

    border-radius: 2px; 
    background-size: 35px 20px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
}

.value-box {
  height: 10px;
  background: #36c36e;
}
```

```html
<div id="skills">
  <p>C++ development</p>
  <progress value="23" max="100"></progress>

  <p>HTML5</p>
  <div class="value">
    <div class="value-box" style="width: 55%;"></div>
  </div>

  <p>.NET</p>
  <div class="value">
    <div class="value-box" style="width: 74%;"></div>
  </div>

  <p>jQuery</p>
  <div class="value">
    <div class="value-box" style="width: 65%;"></div>
  </div>

  <p>Angular</p>
  <div class="value">
    <div class="value-box" style="width: 40%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А какой вариант будет более оптимизированным и удобным для написания?

Comment: Это какой-то вопрос о построении вселенной. Я дал вам код в качестве примера стилизации. Правьте его на свое усмотрение и получайте тот вариант, что вам нужен.

Comment: Большое спасибо:3

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый зеленой галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Comment: Надо только учитывать, что IE 9- [не поддерживает этот тег](http://caniuse.com/#feat=progress)

Comment: @Crantisz не дискуссии ради, в самом деле интересуюсь.Часто встречали заказчиков, которые используют IE6-9 ?

Comment: @KAGGDesign [83%](http://caniuse.com/#feat=progress)

Comment: @Crantisz в ссылке никаких людей нет.  К вашей личной практике она отношения не имеет. Ладно, закроем тему.